# UserStyles for XML activities?

Tags: user-interface, themes, xposed-framework

All my android phones so far have been Samsung's, with AMOLED screens. 
One of the benefits of AMOLED is that black saves battery life.

So many apps though (including many big ones, even from Google) don't include a dark theme.
So you wind up with a lot of white, sucking down your battery.

This got me to wondering, seeing as the Android UI is built on XML with something essentially like CSS, is there any way to override the styles in apps?

I'm thinking something along the lines of the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on for Firefox, which allows you to specify user stylesheets that can override all sites, or specific sites.

I am rooted, and was thinking maybe something on that Xposed Framework?
(I've never used any Xposed modules). Or any way really.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Holo Themer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-holo-themer-force-holo-dark-light-t2768706) which is an xposed module that will force all Holo apps (that is, apps which are consistent to the 3.0+ UI as opposed to the pre-Honeycomb UI) to be either dark or light.

If, after you install xposed, your phone won't boot, boot into recovery and flash the [disabler attached to the thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/xposed-installer-versions-changelog-t2714053).

Comment: Yeah, was excited when I saw that module published on XDA a week or two ago, but it doesn't seem to be effective with many apps. Google apps such as gmail and such seem to crash, and other apps, the developer has explicitly coded various elements to be certain styles, so that even though the activities are re-themed, a lot of the elements on them aren't, leading to a hodge-podge appearance. LOVED the idea, but it didn't really seem to work for me. :(

Comment: If you're willing to flash a custom ROM, you'll definitely want to check out [SlimROM](http://www.slimroms.net/) which lets you make the whole ROM (including the gapps) dark rather than light.